# Cut paper in win32print POS

Tags: python, winapi

I have a Python script that prints to a POS receipt printer and another one for a label printer. The scripts are the same, but only the printer names and text to be printed are given accordingly. The problem I have is that when the POS receipt printer is done, it is not cutting the paper, and the label printer is not moving to the next label. Here is the code:

```
try:
    printer_name = "EPSON T20III"
    raw_data = bytes(recipt.text, "utf-8")

    drivers = win32print.EnumPrinterDrivers(None, None, 2)
    hPrinter = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)
    printer_info = win32print.GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2)
    for driver in drivers:
        if driver["Name"] == printer_info["pDriverName"]:
            printer_driver = driver
   
    raw_type = "XPS_PASS" if printer_driver["Version"] == 4 else "RAW"
    try:
        hJob = win32print.StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, ("test of raw data", None, raw_type))
        try:
            win32print.StartPagePrinter(hPrinter)
            win32print.WritePrinter(hPrinter, raw_data)
            win32print.EndPagePrinter(hPrinter)
    
        except Exception as e:
            message.warning(request, f"Error! {e}")
        finally:
            win32print.EndDocPrinter(hPrinter)  
    except Exception as e:
        message.warning(request, f'Error! {e}')
    finally:
        win32print.ClosePrinter(hPrinter)
except Exception as e:
    message.warning(request, f"Error printing! {e}")
```

Note:I have tried to look for settings in those printers through windows interface but i couldnt find the cut and feed options. Im possitive the printers have that capabilities because right now there is another software useing them and the POS printer is cutting and the label printer is moving to the next label just fine.

I have also tried using this line of code (`win32print.WritePrinter(p, b'\x1dV\x01')`) just after `win32print.WritePrinter(hPrinter, raw_data)`. Also this didnt work: `win32print.WritePrinter(p, b'\x1dV\x00')`